# Choosing a random line based of a "Good" or "Bad" input

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I wanted to make a small program that asks a simple question like 
Did you go to class today?
and the user would enter in "No" or "Yes" (eventually I will be adding in synonyms for those words)
Is there a way I can make a list of actions (such as opening a video link or a picture) based off of a given input?

Example:

```
Did you go to class today? 
User Input: Yes
```

(One line of the many I make displayed here, whether it's a picture, video, or just a simple line of text)

Here's an image example:

[image]

Comment: _Is there a way I can make a list of actions (such as opening a video link or a picture) based off of a given input?_ Yes, that seems rather straightforward.

Comment: `item = random.choice([function_1, function_2, function_3])` and run `item()`

Comment: @furas Your code makes a random choice rather than a choice based on the given input.

Comment: @DYZ yes, it still needs some more work to create answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a very simple code like this:

```py
from random import choice #  choice is a inbuilt function from the random module to randomly select an item from a list.

def rand(a): # a function with 'a' as a parameter
  if a == 'yes':
    yourlist = ['Good Job!', 'Well done!', 'Nice!'] # list with strings items
  elif a == 'no':
    yourlist = ['Oh, no!', 'That is not good', 'I am sorry to hear that']
  return random.choice(yourlist) # the function will return a random choice from the selected list.

print('Did you go to class today?')
answer = input('> ').lower() #  lower() methods returns the lowercased string
print(rand(answer)) # call the function with the parameter 'answer' which is a string.

--------OUTPUT------------------
Did you go to class today?
> yes
Well done!
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll use this to study and learn more about python! I really appreciate it!

Comment: If this worked for you, remember to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: This code is simple but useful if you want to use it within other code. I will comment it for a fully understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I've written the code below. I think it does everything you've asked us for. Let me know if you need anymore help!

```
import random
import webbrowser

# creating functions that do different things for yes and no value
yes_functions = [lambda: 'Good Job!', lambda: 'Well done!', lambda: 'Nice!', lambda: webbrowser.open('https://go.aws/2PQCGpk')]
no_functions = [lambda: 'Oh No!', lambda: 'Thats not good!', lambda: webbrowser.open('https://images.twinkl.co.uk/tr/image/upload/illustation/Sad-Face-1.png')]

# iterates until the user types in either yes or no
while True:
    question = input('Did you go to school today?: ') # saves the answer from the user
    question.lower() # changes the input to always lower case
    if question == 'yes' or question == 'y': # does the next step if either yes of y is chosen
        yes = random.choice(yes_functions) # chooses a random function from the yes_function
        print(yes()) #prints the value in the function
        pass
    elif question == 'no' or question == 'n':
        no = random.choice(no_functions)
        print(no())
        pass
    else:
        continue # iterates until user answers correctly
    break
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! That is very kind of you, I'll dissect your code and try to learn as much as I can! Thank you! (Also your comments are very clear and concise!)